# Wrap HTML to all templates/partials in angularjs but not in index.html not in partial.html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Current**

```
index.html
<body>
    <div id="container" >
        <div id="modal" >
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper mobileWrapper">
            <!-- ui-view contains visible(window) of webpage -->
            <div ui-view=""></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

header.html
<header>
    Header
</header>

footer.html
<footer>
    Header
</footer>

mainPage.html - partial/template
<div ng-include="'header.html'"></div>
<div> Current Page Contents </div>
<div ng-include="'footer.html'"></div>
```

I need to keep only **`<div ui-view=""></div>`**  inside index.html and need to move remaining tags somewhere inside.

In the above example if I used **ng-include** then tags opened in **header.html** needs to be closed in header only.

Is there any alternative ideas

Edit: I got one solution
Before I'm using

```
// Before main.html loading
angular.module 'ngApp'
.config ($stateProvider) ->
  $stateProvider
  .state 'home',
    url: '/'
    templateUrl: 'app/views/main/main.html'
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
// Problem Solved: before wrapped with wrapper.html
angular.module 'ngApp'
.config ($stateProvider) ->
  $stateProvider
  .state 'wrapper',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'app/views/main/wrapper.html'
  .state 'wrapper.home',
    url: '/'
    templateUrl: 'app/views/main/main.html'
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
```

Is there any way to wrap some html for all views.

**not in index.html** 
and 
**not in main.html(partial)**

**Edit 2:**
Before my states like

```
.state 'home',
.state 'about-us',
```

to wrap html I created on abstract state

```
 .state 'wrapper',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'app/views/main/wrapper.html'
```

then I prefixed parent state(wrapper) to all other states

```
.state 'wrapper.home',
.state 'wrapper.about-us',
```

Is there any way to do it without creating a parent state(wrapper)

Comment: your question is not clear... please provide some plnkr link or clarify your question

Comment: I want to wrap some html to all partials. that is easily possible by adding in html but my requirement says, only keep ui-view index.html. then i need to wrap that html in all views(redundant). So i created one abstract parent state for all states. But here the problem is i need to prefix parent state for all states.

Comment: u can use ui-router for such condition... go for that

Comment: I'm using ui-router only. How to do that???